# Excel generation from database using PEAR

Tags: php, mysql, excel, pear

I have a mysql table like this

### product | date  | price

mobile  | jan-14| 150
laptop  | jan-14| 480
mobile  | feb-14| 172

### laptop  | feb-14| 389

By using below code i got an output like this

### product   |jan 14 |feb 14|

mobile    | 150   | 172  |
laptop    | 480   | 389  |

### My PHP code(PEAR)

```
<?php writer, query fetching, worksheet,workbook, etc..on here
$product=array();
$date1=array();
$price=array();
while($rr=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$col=0;
$product[$rr['product']]=$rr['product'];
$date1[$rr['date']]=$rr['date'];
$price[$rr['prodcut']][$rr['date']]=$rr['price'];
}
$row=1;
$col=1;
foreach($date1 as $tkey=>$t)
{
$worksheet->write($row,$col++,$t);
}
$row=2;
foreach($product as $dkey=>$d)
{
$col=0;
$worksheet->write($row,$col++,$d);
foreach($date1 as $tkey=>$t)
{
$worksheet->write($row,$col++,$price[$d][$t]);
}
$row++;
}
$workbook->close();
```

### ?>

But,I need an output along with total of product wise and date wise like below,

### product   |jan 14 |feb 14|Prod total

mobile    | 150   | 172  |  322

### laptop    | 480   | 389  |  869

date total| 630   | 561  |

could anyone help me? Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be like this:

```
foreach($product as $dkey=>$d)
{
   $col=0;
   $worksheet->write($row,$col++,$d);
   $total = 0;
   foreach($date1 as $tkey=>$t)
   {
      $worksheet->write($row,$col++,$price[$d][$t]);
      $total += $price[$d][$t];
   }
   $worksheet->write($row,$col++,$total);
   $row++;
}
```

Comment: that's great..thanks for that..i need column wise total too.. for total of jan and feb..could you?